# Flutter web post request

Tags: flutter, http, web-applications, http-post, flutter-web

I'm trying to make https post request

```
var url =
              "XXX";
          var response = await http.post(url,
              headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
              body: jsonEncode({
                "GroupPrivateToken": "XXX",
                'Items': [
                  {
                    "Quantity": 1.0,
                    "Description": "XXX"
                  }
                ],
                "EmailAddress": "XXX",
                "CustomerLastName": "XXX"
              }));
          print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response.body}');
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 906:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 84:22                                                                                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1450:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 143:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 696:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 725:32                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 519:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1302:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 324:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37312:58                              <fn>
```

I'm using flutter web, someone have an idea?

Comment: Difficult to say. Maybe a problem with the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) configuration? [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing]

Comment: As @Thierry says, the problem probably highly related with `CORS`. Please see the error from your web  Developer Tools, then go to console tab.

Comment: note that after the issue is resolved, your code may or may not work properly, unless you add the: `'Accept': "application/json"` header. Had that issue before, thought i might point it out.